# AngularJs ng-model substr

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I set input value with without first letter of ng-model. I do not want to change model value itself. Just content of input to be without first letter.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVal" >
```

and js

```
$scope.myVal = 'Hello';
```

Wanted result: ello

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you don't want two way data-bindin you can use value instead of ng-model

```
<input type="text" value="{{myVal.substr(1)}}" >
```

If you do want two way databinding, using substr on a model statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: More info : it's not relation to this question but If you want to display only 10 first characters use this<input type="text" value="{{myVal.substr(0,10)}}" >

Answer (score 2):

Have 2 models and use ng-change in your input to update the original model as you change your input model.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('myFilter',function(){
  return function(input){
    input = input.substring(1,input.length);
    return input;
    };
  })
.controller('myController',function($scope,$filter){
  $scope.myValObj = "Hello";
  $scope.myValObj2 = $filter('myFilter')($scope.myValObj);
  $scope.updateOriginal = function(){
    $scope.myValObj = $scope.myValObj[0] + $scope.myValObj2;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myValObj2" ng-change="updateOriginal()"/>
<br>
  Original Model: {{myValObj}}
<br>
  Model For Input: {{myValObj2}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to a css aproach? you could move the text in the input to the left so the first letter is not visible but you would need to make sure your font is monospaced. Or put the filtered/one character model text on top of your input with white color to cover the first letter. And then a function ng-change to keep track of the input and does not let the last letter to be removed, so it would reinsert the last character seen if input.lenght == 0.